# SQL - Using CTEs I get Subquery returned more than 1 value error. This is not permitted when subquery follows =, >,... etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I am currently having a Stored Procedure that needs to calculate Tax for different employees of a given company.

In order to reduce the load of the query and avoid the timeout issues happening, I decided to use CTEs in order to calculate the Income Tax per employee of a given company. Income Tax is used as a basis for many other calculations and I wanted to avoid calculating again and again.

```
WITH 
monthlyTaxCTE (EmployeeID, IncomeTax) AS 
(
SELECT tblEmployees.EmployeeID, -huge SELECT for Tax Calculation-
FROM tblEmployees
WHERE tblEmployees.companyid=@companyid
)
```

I expect the below table to give me the below result

```
EmployeeID | IncomeTax
----------   ---------
144            7000
145            4000
```

Below I am using another CTE with the below code
(GetEmployeeB2 if a function doing extra calculations based on 1.Year, 2.EmployeeID - *in order to find other Employee Contributions*, 3.Income Tax - *from CTE for each employee*)

```
tempCTE AS 
(
...,
tblEmployees.employeeid as [Employee_ID],
dbo.GetEmployeeB2(@Year, tblEmployees.EmployeeID, 
(SELECT IncomeTax FROM monthlyTaxCTE 
INNER JOIN tblEmployees ON monthlyTaxCTE.EmployeeID = tblEmployees.EmployeeID))
AS [Other Deductions],
...
)
```

The table should bring the result

```
EmployeeID | IncomeTax
----------   ---------
144            560
145            420
```

I tried changing the GetEmployeeB2 function to either this:

```
dbo.GetEmployeeB2(@Year, tblEmployees.EmployeeID, 
(SELECT IncomeTax FROM monthlyTaxCTE WHERE tblEmployees.EmployeeID 
IN (SELECT EmployeeID FROM monthlyTaxCTE))
```

or this:

```
dbo.GetEmployeeB2(@Year, tblEmployees.EmployeeID, 
(SELECT IncomeTax AS mTaxValue FROM monthlyTaxCTE AS mTaxTable 
INNER JOIN tblEmployees ON mTaxTable.EmployeeID = tblEmployees.EmployeeID))
```

but the error given is always

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

The code works fine when the company has 1 employee, but always breaks with 2 or more.
How can I achieve the functionality I want?

Comment: What's not clear here, the SubQuery shouldn't returns more than 1 row while yours does.

Comment: You are telling me that CTEs cannot return more than 1 row??

Comment: Perform a normal join instead of a subquery. Then every value you pass to your function will be handled independently. Better yet, make your function inline table-valued, then you can just cross apply to it...

Comment: This has nothing to do with the CTE. Try `SELECT name, (SELECT physical_name FROM sys.master_files WHERE database_id = d.database_id)
FROM sys.databases AS d;` That subquery has to return a single value for each row. It can't unless you introduce a TOP, MAX, or some other struct that filters all but one row.

Comment: @KMarinis88 I say your SubQuery, not your CTE.

Comment: Isn't this:
*ON monthlyTaxCTE.EmployeeID = tblEmployees.EmployeeID*
exluding scenarios with multiple rows?
(EmployeeID is set as Unique)

Comment: No. Run this query by itself, how many rows do you get? `SELECT IncomeTax FROM monthlyTaxCTE 
INNER JOIN tblEmployees ON monthlyTaxCTE.EmployeeID = tblEmployees.EmployeeID` - you've introduced `tblEmployees` a second time. Stop doing this in a subquery.

Comment: Oh, boy..
First of all yes.. The INNER JOIN was a leftover, which I somehow missed for a whole lot of time.
So the query now is```dbo.GetEmployeeB2(@Year, tblEmployees.EmployeeID, (SELECT IncomeTax FROM monthlyTaxCTE WHERE monthlyTaxCTE.EmployeeID = tblEmployees.EmployeeID))```. Still though I get the same error

Comment: I added aliases and replaced again all the instances with the new code. Seems to be working now. It was either the aliases or some forgotten code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your CTE:

```
tempCTE AS (
 select ...,
        tblEmployees.employeeid as [Employee_ID],
        dbo.GetEmployeeB2(@Year, tblEmployees.EmployeeID, 
        (SELECT IncomeTax
         FROM monthlyTaxCTE INNER JOIN
             tblEmployees
             ON monthlyTaxCTE.EmployeeID = tblEmployees.EmployeeID
        ) AS [Other Deductions],
        ...
 )
```

It is highly suspicious repeating the table name in the subquery.  Normally, one would just use a correlated subquery:

```
tempCTE AS (
 select ...,
        tblEmployees.employeeid as [Employee_ID],
        dbo.GetEmployeeB2(@Year, tblEmployees.EmployeeID, 
        (SELECT t.IncomeTax
         FROM monthlyTaxCTE t
         WHERE t.EmployeeID = tblEmployees.EmployeeID
        ) AS [Other Deductions],
        ...
 )
```

Comment: Thanks.. Somehow I had the INNER JOIN being left over from some old code. Works like a charm now..